# This is a reserved word - error in function other than on a return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I`m trying to access an api and simply store the objects(that I get from it) in the state every time I click on a button, but once I try to *npm start* it, it gives *Syntax error: this is a reserved word.*
I dont know why this is happening and I want some answers, and if by any means you see any flaw or way to improve my code feel free to tell me as well.
Here is the code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            personagens: [],
            page: 1,
        };
        this.getNextPers = this.getNextPers.bind(this);
    }

    getNextPers(){
        let URL = 'https://swapi.com/api/people/'+{this.state.page};
        axios.get(URL).then((p) => this.setState({ personages: [...{this.state.personagens}, ...p], page: {this.state.page}+1 }));
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Personagens</p>
                {this.state.personagens.map(pers, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <p>{pers.name}</p>
                    </div>
                )}
                <button onClick={this.getNextPerson}>Proximo Personagem</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Got a feeling it's this (no pun intended) `let URL = 'https://swapi.com/api/people/'+{this.state.page};`. Should there be curly braces around `this.state.page`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `let URL = 'https://swapi.com/api/people/'+{this.state.page};` the curly braces are the problem. Try either:

`const URL = 'https://swapi.com/api/people/' + this.state.page`

or

`` const URL = `https://swapi.com/api/people/${this.state.page}` ``

(both works)

I agree with the others that lowercase `url` might be a better choice for a variable name.

Comment: thank you for the help, but now it not in the this from the url but on the this from the *this.state.personagens*, do you guys have any other ideas?

Comment: couldn't you just increment like this `this.state.page++`? At least the "reserved keyword this" thing should be solved, right?

Answer (score 1):

`URL` is a poor choice of variable name, and is likely the reserved word referenced in the error you've mentioned. Perhaps choose something more along the lines of `peopleApiEndpoint`.

General feedback:

- Use `const` as opposed to `let`, when declaring the aforementioned variable. You never make a reassignment to this variable. [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) as further reference material.
- Don't use an index as a `key` when iterating over elements. `pers.name` would perhaps be a better choice of key. [Read this](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) as further reference material.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I added the changes to the code